# Oracle Database 11g: oe.orders table doesn't exist

Tags: database, oracle

I try to create a simple function in Oracle Database 11g, but it gives me the following error. It seems like it couldn't find the oe.orders table. Would you please help!

Thanks!

Code:

```
--Create following function as SYS
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_bal(acc_no IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS acc_bal NUMBER(11,2);
  BEGIN
    SELECT oe.orders.order_total
    INTO acc_bal
    FROM oe.orders
    WHERE oe.orders.customer_id = acc_no;
    RETURN(acc_bal);
  END;
/

SELECT get_bal(170) AS Balance FROM dual;
```

ERROR:

```
> ORA-06575: Package or function GET_BAL is in an invalid state
> 06575. 00000 -  "Package or function %s is in an invalid state"
> *Cause:    A SQL statement references a PL/SQL function that is in an
>            invalid state. Oracle attempted to compile the function, but
>            detected errors.
> *Action:   Check the SQL statement and the PL/SQL function for syntax
>            errors or incorrectly assigned, or missing, privileges for a
>            referenced object. Error at Line: 28 Column: 7
```

Comment: That error just tells you the function didn't compile. You need to `SHOW ERRORS` to find out what the compilation error actually was. It is most probably a problem with `oe.orders`, but you haven't determined yet what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not be creating any objects as `SYS`.  `SYS` is Oracle's schema-- only objects that Oracle creates should be placed in that schema. Though it is probably not the cause of your particular problem, various functionality behaves differently when you are `SYS` than it does when you are any normal user-- another reason to avoid using the `SYS` schema.

Second, does the table `oe.orders` exist?  The `OE` schema is one of the sample schemas that ships with the Oracle database.  It may or may not exist in any particular database.  If the schema does not exist, we can walk you through installing it.  Otherwise, the problem is likely one of permissions.  If you are not sure whether the table exists, does this return any rows?

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM dba_tables
 WHERE owner = 'OE'
   AND table_name = 'ORDERS'
```

Third, if you want to query a table owned by user `A` (in this case `OE`) in a procedure or function owned by user `B` (whatever user you decide to use rather than `SYS`), the owner of the procedure has to have been granted access on the table directly not via a role.  If the table exists, in all probability `SYS` has access to the table only via a role `DBA` rather than having direct access.  That prevents `SYS` from owning a function that references the table.  To fix that, you need to log in as `A` and grant `SELECT` access on the table to `B`.  So, as `OE`, you would need to

```
GRANT SELECT ON oe.orders TO <<user that will own the function>>
```

Comment: would you please show me how to install oe schema?? I try the following code in SQL*Plus: Alternatively you can issue the following SQL*Plus commands:

ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE to hr;

ALTER USER oe IDENTIFIED BY OE ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE to OE;

However, it just work with HR only, the 'OE' does not exit. I try to unlock using SQL developer the same way I unclocked HR but I do not find OE anywhere.
Thanks!!

Comment: @user1623650 - What version of Oracle are you using and what edition of the database are you using?  The `OE` schema depends on the availability of the Spatial option-- did you install Spatial?

Comment: Im using the Oracle Database 11g Express edition. I don't think I have install Spatial yet :D

Comment: @user1623650 - The express edition does not include the Spatial option so the `OE` schema isn't included.  You can use the `HR` sample schema.

Comment: I search online and see that the express edition user can obtain the OE schema here: slimlab.net/downloads/viewdownload/4-database/5-oracle-database-sample-schemas-oe-order-entry.html and then run oe_main.sql as SYS. I have download and extract it to demo/schema folder, but was not able to manually install the oe schema. Do you know how they did it? Many Thanks!!

Comment: @user1623650 - It's easy enough to get the `oe_main.sql`.  I'm just not sure I understand why you need the `OE` schema specifically when it leverages Spatial and the express edition doesn't support Spatial.  It would seem much more sensible to use a different sample schema that the express edition does support or to install a version of the database that ships with the `OE` sample schema.

Comment: I am learning using CBT nuggets tutorial videos, so I just want to follow along and practice with the lesson :). May be I will try to  install a version of the database that ships with the OE sample schema. Thanks again!! :)